# Как правильно добавить свой метод в namedtuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, tuple

Есть вот такой "игрушечный" пример

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, color, mileage):
        self.color = color
        self.mileage = mileage
    
    def check_mileage(self): 
        if self.mileage > 10000: 
            print('Машина с большим пробегом')
        else: 
            print('Машина с маленьким пробегом')
```

Но если я пробую переписать это на `namedtuple`, то с методом проблемы:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Car = namedtuple('Авто' , 'color mileage check_mileage')

def check_mileage(self): 
        if self.mileage > 10000: 
            print('Машина с большим пробегом')
        else: 
            print('Машина с маленьким пробегом')

c1 = Car('Красный', 14000, check_mileage)

c1.check_mileage() # TypeError: check_mileage() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

c1.check_mileage(c1) # Машина с большим пробегом
```

Я отдельно объявил функцию и её передал как один из аргументов. Но она почему-то теряет `self`, поэтому каждый раз приходится передавать его явно.

В книге нет примера с методами. Можно ли написать так, чтобы `self` не передавать каждый раз?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Рабочий вариант - отнаследоваться от созданного `namedtuple` с добавлением своего метода:

```
from collections import namedtuple


class Car(namedtuple('Авто' , 'color mileage')):
    def check_mileage(self): 
        if self.mileage > 10000: 
            print('Машина с большим пробегом')
        else: 
            print('Машина с маленьким пробегом')


c1 = Car('Красный', 14000)

c1.check_mileage()
```

Также можно использовать "новый" (c Python 3.6) [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) с объявлением в стиле датаклассов, сразу объявить класс с нужным методом:

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class Car(NamedTuple):
    color: str
    mileage: int

    def check_mileage(self): 
        if self.mileage > 10000: 
            print('Машина с большим пробегом')
        else: 
            print('Машина с маленьким пробегом')


c1 = Car('Красный', 14000)

c1.check_mileage()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я так понял, сам по себе namedtuple не поддерживает создание методов?

Comment: Да, напрямую не поддерживает. Возможно есть какие-то магические способы как привязать отдельную функцию к классу, чтобы она стала bound методом (чтобы self автоматом передавался), но даже если такой способ есть - лучше по-простому, через наследование или через NamedTuple.

Comment: @DarkSpace Наследоваться от класса с добавлением своих методов - это правильная парадигма ООП, привыкайте к ней